# Getting json response from CGI doesn't work with AJAX

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, perl, cgi

My JS code is like this. I am basically testing to get a json response back from CGI. But what I get is "failed". Looks like cgi is not properly opened

```
    $.ajax({
        url     : 'perl.cgi',
        method  : 'post',
        data    : "username=" + name + "&birthday=" + birthday,
        success : function(response) {
            alert(response);
        },
        error: function (request) {
            alert("failed");
        }
    });
```

My CGI:

```
use CGI;
use strict;
use warnings;
use JSON;

my $cgi = CGI->new;
my $word = 'hey';
print $cgi->header('application/json');
print to_json($word);
```

If I use `print $cgi->header('text/plain;charset=UTF-8');`, the call will be successful but nothing shows in my alert from `alert(response)`.

Any suggestion?

Comment: add `dataType:'json'` in ajax

Comment: tried, still not successful

Comment: open the ajaxed page in a browser window and see the errors , i think to_json can't convert a string to json, better use a array

Comment: Yup..that's the problem. I used an array and encode_json instead and  it works now